# Regex to match isolated 4-digit years

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match years (e.g. 1975 or 2019) in a text line.

The regexp `[12][09]\d\d` leads to the right matches, but I would like to fine-tune it such that it doesn't match the year portion of a longer timestamp, i.e. 01.01.2019 should **not** give a match.

I tried to prepend a word boundary `\b[12][09]\d\d` but the dot seems to satisfy that, too.

Comment: What do you expect to match and not match? Can you list some examples? Also, are you aware `[12][09]` will match `29..` and `10..`? Maybe you want `20|19`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?<!\d\.)(?:19|20)\d\d\b(?!\.\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/29MuM2/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\d\.)` - right before the current location, there must be no digit followed with a dot
- `(?:19|20)` - `19` or `20`
- `\d\d` - any two digits
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!\.\d)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there should be no `.` and a digit.

Comment: There are variations of the pattern, let know if you need to adjust the pattern.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. But geez, no wonder I couldn't come up with this on my own :)